# Subscription based nosql in-memory database

Tags: javascript, node.js, gun, nosql

I need subscription based in-memory database where I can have callbacks on my data change (I'll use it for my tests only). I used [gunDB](https://github.com/amark/gun), and it works only this way:

```
var Gun = require('gun');
var key = 'something_long';
var state = { a: 1, b: 2 };
var gun1 = Gun();
var gun2 = Gun();

gun1.put(state).key(key);

gun2.get(key).on(function(val) {
    console.log('Value for gun2 (using ".on") is: ');
    console.dir(val);
});
```

When I swap `gun1.put` and `gun2.get` it doesn't work. It means that I can't really subscribe until key is not there. This example doesn't work (callback never gets called):

```
var Gun = require('gun');
var key = 'something_long';
var state = { a: 1, b: 2 };
var gun1 = Gun();
var gun2 = Gun();

gun2.get(key).on(function(val) {
    console.log('Value for gun2 (using ".on") is: ');
    console.dir(val);
});

gun1.put(state).key(key);
```

I'm not too familiar with all available in-memory databases, and I appreciate if anyone can suggest something.

The same example works for firebase:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var statesRef = new Firebase('https://******.firebaseio.com/states');
var statesRef2 = new Firebase('https://******.firebaseio.com/states');

var key = 'something_very_long';
var data = { a: 1, b: 2 };

statesRef2.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
    console.dir(dataSnapshot.val());
});
statesRef.set({ key: key, state: data });
```

Comment: Ive use Reddis in the past in php, worked great ! Probably available in nodejs

Comment: @AndrewDonovan the main disadvantage is that you have to have Redis server running. And I'll use it for tests only, so it's kinda overhead for me.

Answer (score 2):

Creating separate/multiple GUN instances isn't useful or necessary.

Everything works if you just use 1 GUN instance:

http://jsbin.com/yorujufofe/edit?js,console

It also works in NodeJS.

The `val` object returned to you is a safe copied snapshot, **mutating it will NOT effect the database state**.

I hope this is helpful.